# Will the app be reject because it uses CoreVideo.framework?

Tags: ios, core-video

According to the apple document, CoreVideo.framework is "Contains low-level routines for manipulating audio and video. Do not use this framework directly."

So, will my app be reject if i use it?

Comment: As Kreiri said: You can safely add it with the rest of needed frameworks. Just don't use it's unlisted (private) API's.

Answer (score 3):

"Do not use X framework directly" usually means "add this framework to your app if needed (for example, framework Y also needs X to work), but do not use functions\classes\etc from it directly".

Answer (score 2):

If there are public functions in a framework you are probably ok to use them, if there are only private functions you are going to likely have issues.
developers who think that there are clear cut guidelines that avoid apple rejections are in for a rude surprise. If you submit on the wrong phase of the moon you may get rejected.

The only list you can come up with are of paths that will likely lead to rejection,for that there is a document or two on the apple site.

1) use of private api's (I have never really seen the reasoning behind this rule, and having been a developer on all kind of platforms for a long time the apple explanation about forward compatibility seems very shallow, and again it depends how obvious it is and what reviewer you get.

2) don't do things that would keep apple from getting revenue they would normally get, like try to curcumvent in-app purchases. been there / done that , its not worth the risk.

3) work with the reviewers don't treat them like an adversary.

4) get some kind of talisment or pray a lot.  And once your in the app store don't think your safe many apps including some I helped developed got pulled after a short stay.

My rule of thumb is don't do anything non-standard in your apps and your fine, but then the app is boring and common, risks equal more revenue but then you have to be prepared to take the risks.

Comment: 1) Not at all - Apple platforms are possibly the worst offenders when it comes to compatibility (backwards or forwards). You can pretty much expect compatibility to be broken whenever you try to run software written for a platform 2 or more point releases newer or 2 or more point releases older. And that's using the publicly documented APIs. There's no guarantee that the private APIs will continue working beyond the next routinely scheduled "Apple Software Update". They have a right to be anal about this, since they designed such a poor platform for compatibility in the first place.